# How to remove particular filters from a specific category?

Tags: magento2.4, xml, layered-navigation, sidebar

I want to remove the color and price filter only for the specific category in Magento 2.4.3-p1.

I created a separate XML file (catalog_category_view_id_{category_id}.xml) and apply the below code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
           <referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav">
               <action method="hide">
                   <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">price</argument>
               </action>       
               <action method="hide">
                   <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">color</argument>
               </action>       
           </referenceBlock>
       </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I get the below error.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation::hide
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to do this using the admin site?

Comment: @MuhammadMuizAther No, I want to remove it from the frontend side only.

Comment: I guess that you have an issue with the collection call.

Maybe you need to do indexing.

Comment: @MuhammadMuizAther Appreciate your comment. It's not related to the collection. It's a simple category with products but I need only selected filters for one category. Hope it's clear now. Thank you

Comment: I would add some logic in the filter template directly.. if category name =='' then hide color.. All this with a viewModel is the recommended way but not compulsory

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy I'm aware of this code logic but I want to know if there is any direct method available using XML file OR not. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the template for rendering the filters is: `vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/frontend/templates/layer/filter.phtml` (as you know)

In this template, we can see a viewModel `/** @var \Magento\LayeredNavigation\ViewModel\Layer\Filter $viewModel */`

You could create a preference for this viewModel and add some custom logic that would check if the category can display color or not. This logic could be:

- comparing category name to a list of names coming from your config
- if the number of filter items is lower than 2 for instance, then hide the filter

I do believe you were looking at a setting in XML or in the backend and I do not believe there is anything like this